# setcookie() expects parameter 2 to be string, array what is the problem?

Tags: php, cookies, isset, setcookie

What is the problem?

```
while($rov = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
    $expire = time()+(60*60*24*30);
    setcookie('cookie',$rov,$expire);
    $userID = $rov;
}

if(isset($_COOKIE['cookie'])) {
    $userID = $_COOKIE['ID'];
}

if(isset($_COOKIE['cookie'])) {}
```

The error message:

> Warning: setcookie() expects parameter 2 to be string, array given in /index.php on line 24

Comment: what is the value of `$rov`? only the string is allowable as 2nd paramerter. See  http://php.net/manual/en/function.setcookie.php

Comment: `mysql_fetch_array` returns an array not a string.

Comment: **Danger**:  You are using [an **obsolete** database API](http://stackoverflow.com/q/12859942/19068) which has been **removed** entirely from the all supported versions of PHP. You should use a [modern replacement](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqlinfo.api.choosing.php) and upgrade to a version of PHP which receives security fixes.

Comment: Be glad you're getting a warning. When you cast a array to string you only get the word "Array" ([literally](https://3v4l.org/lQ75S)) so the error would have gone unnoticed.

Answer (score 5):

You're getting the  warning

> Warning: setcookie() expects parameter 2 to be string, array given in
>   /index.php on line 24

because PHP's [setcookie()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.setcookie.php) function accepts **string** as the 2nd parameter. So if you want to store any array values e.g `$rov` then you can use `json_encode($rev);` to set cookie, to access it you can use `json_decode($_COOKIE['cookie'],1);`

This is the way to set and get cookie for **Array** values using [json_encode()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php) and [json_decode()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php)

**Setting Cookie**

```
setcookie('cookie', json_encode($rov), time()+3600);
```

**Getting Cookie**

```
$data = json_decode($_COOKIE['cookie'], true);
```

Comment: Please attach link to PHP Manual. `JSON_ENCODE` could be better and more secure in this case, too.

Comment: Yes I know, Just editing my answer. Thanks. for reminding sir

Answer (score 0):

**setCookie()** expects string as value but **$rov** variable contains an array which causing the error.

you may use **json_encode/json_decode** solution suggested by @Curious_mind or can take **serialize/unserialize** approach.

```
setcookie('cookie', serialize($rov), time()+3600);

Then unserialize data:

$data = unserialize($_COOKIE['cookie'], ["allowed_classes" => false]);
```